# putItem(itemRequest) works during JUnit test but not during test on AWS Lambda console

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following code for a putItem JAVA function in Lambda. The function is working properly till the line `client.putItem(itemRequest);`. The function is reading the input properly. This entire code is working properly when doing a JUnit4 test (Total time < 2sec), and I can see the entries in the database. But this fails (Times Out after 5secs) when a test using the Lambda console at the putItem line.

```
public class HelloDB implements RequestHandler<UserClass, String> {
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = null;

public HelloDB() throws IOException {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(HelloDB.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));
    client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
    System.out.println("Creds created");
}

@Override
public String handleRequest(UserClass input, Context context) {
    System.out.println("U: " + input.getUserName() + " p: " + input.getPasswordHash());
    System.out.println("UI: " + input.userId + " O: " + input.getOpenIdToken());

    String tableName = "User";

    Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();

    item.put("userName", new AttributeValue().withS(input.getUserName()));
    item.put("passwordHash", new AttributeValue().withS(input.getPasswordHash()));
    item.put("userId", new AttributeValue().withN(input.getUserId().toString()));
    item.put("openIdToken", new AttributeValue().withS(input.getOpenIdToken()));

    PutItemRequest itemRequest = new PutItemRequest().withTableName(tableName).withItem(item);
    System.out.println("item request");
    client.putItem(itemRequest);
    System.out.println("client put item request");
    item.clear();
    return "Success";
}
```

Here is the error Message:

```
"errorMessage": .... Task timed out after 5.00 seconds"
```

When the time is increased to 15 seconds instead of 5seconds then I get this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Metaspace",
"errorType": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
```

Comment: "It fails" is not really a helpful description; the "how" is pretty important if you actually want us to help you.

Comment: It times out. So basically it is not able to putItem...

Comment: Did you enable VPC access for the Lambda function?

Comment: @MarkB No I haven't. But Lambda function is connecting to DynamoDB so I don't think it would be requiring VPC

Comment: VPC would actually prevent connection to DynamoDB, which is why I asked. How do you know it is connecting to DynamoDB if you are getting timeouts? Have you tried increasing the timeout to more than 5 seconds (which is pretty low for a Java Lambda function) to see if it just needs more time to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function isn't getting any requests then Amazon will automatically delete it from the Lambda servers so it isn't using any resources. If this has happened then the next time a request comes in, the function has to be redeployed to a Lambda server before it can handle the request. This is called a "cold start"

I takes longer and much more resources for a lambda function written in JAVA to run from a cold start compared to ones written in python or nodejs. Hence, it would be advisable to allocate a minimum of 10 sec time limit and 512MB memory to start. Consequent runs take about 20-30 ms.

Here is a study on the cold start time and the consequent run times for a function written in all the 3 languages.

JUnit4 test runs faster than Lambda may be attributed to the cold start.